# PostgreSQL - Function to return multiple columns

Tags: database, postgresql

Here's a function that provides a result of 2 columns.

In this function there's a `Loop` been used to return the result.

**Function :**

```
Create Type Repeat_rs as (
label text,
count bigint
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Repeat(fromDate date,toDate date)
returns SETOF  Repeat_rs
AS 
$$
Declare someVariableName Repeat_rs;
BEGIN
    For someVariableName in (
        SELECT label, count(*) AS Cnt from test where date between fromDate and toDate group by circle
    ) Loop
    Return Next someVariableName;
    End Loop;
    Return;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there any possibilities of returning the rows without using loop?

If so please do share me on how we can do it.

And will I be able to write a function to insert records on to a table without using loop?

Help me out to solve this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't which one to accept but both gave me the answer what i was expecting for. Hence +1 for both the answers.

Comment: Note that your query is not valid: you group only by `circle`, but use `label` as a selected column. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY

Comment: That needs to label. That was a typo error. By the way the query will not run if i don't include label in the `groupby`.

Comment: You should accept a_horse_with_no_name's answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you don't need the extra type definition. And to return multiple rows, use `return query`:

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Repeat(fromDate date,toDate date)
  returns table (label text, cnt bigint)
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    Return query 
       SELECT label, count(*) AS Cnt 
       from test 
       where date between fromDate and toDate
       group by label;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You don't even need a PL/pgSQL function, you can use a simple SQL function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Repeat(fromDate date, toDate date)
  returns table (label text, cnt bigint)
AS 
$$
   SELECT label, count(*) AS Cnt 
   from test 
   where date between fromDate and toDate
   group by label;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: +1, but forgot the `group by circle` clause. Also `label` is not a valid column if it's not in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score -2):

You can insert values in the table using SELECT query as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Repeat(fromDate date,toDate date)
returns VOID 
AS 
$$

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
         SELECT label, count(*) AS Cnt from test where date between fromDate and toDate group by circle
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```